# Sorting ForiegnKey Objects in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model that has two main classes.

The first is the book model and the second is the page model

The pages have a foreign key field to the books which lets me access them but what I am curious about is, how would you implement page numbers such that when creating a new page object, the number is limited only to be within the current length of pages? Furthermore, if it is inserted, how would you shift the following pages down one in number?

Right now I just have an integer field that I manually type in the page number but if I want to allow users to add pages themselves later, that won't do.

UPDATED:

```
class Textbook(models.Model):
    founder = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, 
                              blank=True, 
                              null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Page(models.Model):
    textbook = models.ForeignKey(Textbook, related_name="pages")
    page_title = models.CharField(max_length = 256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.page_title


class Section(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page,related_name="sections")
    section_title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    text = RichTextField(config_name='awesome_ckeditor')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.section_title
```

So above is my model, what I am trying to do is make it so that you can keep track of pages, which are contained in `TextBook`s, in order. Furthermore, you can insert a new page and the page numbers will change accordingly. So if you say have pages 1,2,3 and want to add a new one, you can add a new one as page 4, or insert it in between 2 and 3 and the former page 3 becomes page 4.

Comment: What database are you using? If postgres, it would be better to implement the pages as a json field.

Comment: So... a `deque` of sorts? My first "naive" answer would be two self-`ForeignKey`s and a clever `save()` function, but *thud* "there must be a better way".  Using a JSON-based solution would be an alternative, but might be a problem depending on what you plan on doing.

Comment: @RaphaëlGomès Thats what I figured. But I agree there must be a better way. How easy is it to convert from sqlite (what I am using now) to JSON?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I am currently using sqlite, but it is early enough into the project I can probably switch over if you think it may be easier.

Comment: PostgreSQL is a great backend, SQLite is only good for sandbox projects. It takes some setting up though, but nothing too crazy.

Comment: So what would the PostreSQL solution be? I have never used PostreSQL but I assume I can interface with it pretty easily through the model correct?

Comment: See the docs for the `JSONField` https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield

Comment: Would it be possible to keep a rich text field within a json field?

Answer (score 1):

Does the 'order_with_respect' option the answer at your question:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#order-with-respect-to

Comment: That would be a good way to do it. But you should still switch to PostgreSQL Peter. ^^

Comment: So I am probably going to do this, but when would I call `set_RELATED_order` when inserting a new page?

Comment: You will need to get the order, insert your `Page`'s ID in the list, and set the order back when adding a `Page` to the `Textbook`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather improvised solution that I came up with a long time ago, but you might give it a go. What you can do is to use a `CharField`.

So for example, you have a book with the following pages:

```
1 1.1 2 2.1 2.11 2.111 3 4 5 6 7 8.11
```

When you insert a new page into the book just add another `1` to the end of the page number or decimal field. Then you can just occasionally run a maintenance task to just clean up all the numbers back to `1 2 3 4`, so that you can routinely discard the extra decimals.

You can take a look at the following python code:

```
In [2]: l
Out[2]: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '4.1', '4.11', '4.11', '5', '6', '1.1']

In [3]: sorted(l)
Out[3]: ['1', '1.1', '2', '3', '4', '4.1', '4.11', '4.11', '5', '6']

In [4]: l.append('5.1')

In [5]: sorted(l)
Out[5]: ['1', '1.1', '2', '3', '4', '4.1', '4.11', '4.11', '5', '5.1', '6']
```

You can create a routine task, using a [django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/) to run every once in a while in the background.